# BizTalk - Multiple Conditions in Decide Shape

Tags: expression, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

In my BizTalk Decide shape, How can I handle below conditions in one decide shape node?

code == 'code1'
code == 'code2'
code == 'code3'
code == 'code4'

I'm trying to do, this by

```
(code == 'code1' Or code == 'code2' Or code == 'code3' Or code == 'code4' )
```

But It is not working, please suggest.

Comment: Funny question... 
(code == "code1" || code == "code2" || code == "code3" || code == "code4")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Decide Shape takes any (mostly) C# formatted condition so you would use:

```
(code == "code1") || (code == "code2") || (code == "code3") || (code == "code4")
```

You have to use the double quote since the single quote specifically means char data, not string.